# Multiple type mismatches in this program

Tags: haskell, types

I have a Linux folder with many files some of which are binary while others are script file where the first line contains `#! /bin/bash` or similar. I am trying to read first line of such files, split that line and print out a list of last member (indicating program used):

```
import Control.Exception(catch, IOException)
import System.IO(IOMode(ReadMode), withFile, hGetLine)
import Data.Maybe(catMaybes)
import Data.List
import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents, doesFileExist, getFileSize)
import System.FilePath ((</>))
import Control.Monad(filterM)

getAbsoluteDirContents :: String -> IO [FilePath]
getAbsoluteDirContents dir = do
    contents <- getDirectoryContents dir
    return $ map (dir </>) contents

readFirstLine :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe String)
readFirstLine fp = withFile fp ReadMode $
    \h -> (catch (fmap Just (hGetLine h))
        ((const :: a -> IOException -> a) (return Nothing)))

hasSlash :: String -> Bool
hasSlash firline = do
    elem '/' firline

-- main :: IO ()
main = do
    print
    $ map last              -- get only last string
    $ map splitOn "/"       -- split first line
    $ filter hasSlash       -- filter out those that do not have '/'
    $ catMaybes             -- get Just ones
    $ map readFirstLine     -- read first line of each file
    $ filter doesFileExist  -- filter out dirs
    $ getAbsoluteDirContents "." -- get a list of all files & dirs
```

In the main function, execution will be going from below up!

However, above code is giving multiple type mismatches:

```
soq_firstline6.hs:28:11: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[String] -> [[b0]]’
                  with actual type ‘[b1]’
    • The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
      but its type ‘[b1]’ has none
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘map splitOn "/"
         $ filter hasSlash
           $ catMaybes
             $ map readFirstLine
               $ filter doesFileExist $ getAbsoluteDirContents "."’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘map last
         $ map splitOn "/"
           $ filter hasSlash
             $ catMaybes
               $ map readFirstLine
                 $ filter doesFileExist $ getAbsoluteDirContents "."’

soq_firstline6.hs:28:15: error:
    • Variable not in scope: splitOn :: Char -> b1
    • Perhaps you meant ‘splitAt’ (imported from Data.List)

soq_firstline6.hs:31:7: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO (Maybe String)’ with ‘Maybe String’
      Expected type: [Maybe String]
        Actual type: [IO (Maybe String)]
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘map readFirstLine
         $ filter doesFileExist $ getAbsoluteDirContents "."’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘catMaybes
         $ map readFirstLine
           $ filter doesFileExist $ getAbsoluteDirContents "."’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘filter hasSlash
         $ catMaybes
           $ map readFirstLine
             $ filter doesFileExist $ getAbsoluteDirContents "."’

soq_firstline6.hs:32:14: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO Bool’ with ‘Bool’
      Expected type: FilePath -> Bool
        Actual type: FilePath -> IO Bool
    • In the first argument of ‘filter’, namely ‘doesFileExist’
      In the expression: filter doesFileExist
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘filter doesFileExist $ getAbsoluteDirContents "."’

soq_firstline6.hs:33:7: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[FilePath]’
                  with actual type ‘IO [FilePath]’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘getAbsoluteDirContents "."’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘filter doesFileExist $ getAbsoluteDirContents "."’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘map readFirstLine
         $ filter doesFileExist $ getAbsoluteDirContents "."’
```

How can these errors be corrected. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can not do a `map readFirstLine` here, since then you get a list `[IO (Maybe String)]` back.

Comment: What should be done and is this the only error? A full answer is requested.

Comment: I think it would really benefit, if you first try to understand the difference between an `IO a` and an `a`, this looks like the key concept you are missing here.

Comment: I love that you are learning haskell but it's really not very good at this sort of thing. `for f in *; do head -n 1 $f | perl -nle '/.*\/(.*)/ && print $1'; done` will do the job.

Comment: @luqui sure Perl will do it in less characters... but that doesn't mean it's necessarily the better tool for the task.

Comment: @luqui Will this perl code skip binary files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not just use `filter doesFileExists` here, since `doesFileExists` is a `FilePath -> IO Bool` function, not a `FilePath -> Bool` function, the same happens with `map readFirstLine`, by using `map`, you are building a `[IO (Maybe String)]`, not an `IO [Maybe String]`. You furthermore forgot to use brackets for your `map (splitOn "/")`.

You can fix this by using `filterM` and `mapM` here:

```
main = do
    fps <- getAbsoluteDirContents "."
    fexists <- filterM doesFileExist fps
    flines <- mapM readFirstLine fexists
    print
      $ map last              -- get only last string
      $ map (splitOn "/")     -- split first line
      $ filter hasSlash       -- filter out those that do not have '/'
      $ catMaybes flines      -- get Just ones
```

or a desugared variant:

```
main :: IO ()
main = getAbsoluteDirContents "." >>= filterM doesFileExist >>= mapM readFirstLine >>= print . map (last . splitOn "/") . filter hasSlash . catMaybes
```

Your `hasSlash` makes use of a `do`, but you here do not use a monad at all, so it is better to write this as a simple:

```
hasSlash :: String -> Bool
hasSlash = elem '/'
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. Is there any way to combine first 3 statements into 1 like last 6 statements?

Comment: @rnso: you can desugar the do, so `main = getAbsoluteDirContents "." >>= filterM doesFileExist >>= mapM readFirstLine >>= print . map last . map (splitOn "/") . filter hasSlash . catMaybes`

Comment: Very nice. Haskell is very versatile.